# AngularJs $http deforms request url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, header, http-post

I'm pretty new to AngularJS, but for some reason i have to use it and create small web-page, to be able to sent some requests to my Web Api 2 part. I`m stuck with one strange error. My Controller is in ApplicationFrontEnd/MainView folder, file is called "main.js". Problem part of code :

```
    var request = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/login',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded
        }
    }
    $http(request)
       .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          // I`m supposed to have no problem
       })
       .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           //but for some reason i do have.
       });
```

So, at the point of sending post request is sent not to `'api/login'` , but to `'ApplicationFrontEnd/api/login'`, and do not have any Authorization header. 
On Web Api part of project i have `CORS` turned on, etc., but while i have wrong url in request, i receive 404 error (pretty logical). Can someone please explain to me, what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http you can find a section about http headers. You will find Authentication under common ones.

Comment: @V_Maenolis thx, i saw it. Can you say anything about request uri deformation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the url absolute by adding a leading `/`

```
url: '/api/login'
```

Will make calls to `http://yourDomain.com/api/login`.

Comment: THX! This leading `/` did the trick. Not obvious thing about absolute url (for me, at least).

Comment: i told i`m new to Angular. In .net there is kinda few properties in Uri class , and i can anytime check if my Uri is absolute. But in that JS - there is nothing like that, so that's was not obvious )